# How can I find the most expensive product in a Product table without using MAX, LIMIT, or ORDER BY in SQL Developer Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm supposed to find it without using those, and I can't think of anything and haven't found any information. Thanks

Comment: If I were asked this question in a job interview, I'd respond by asking "why the artificial limitations on using the normal methods?"

Comment: That is a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   product p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   product x
  WHERE  p.price < x.price
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Could you break down the logic of this? I'm not sure I understand what is happening.

Comment: @Szaumoor Select any products `p` where there does not exist another product `x` where `p`'s price is less than `x`'s price (i.e. `p` has the maximum price as there are no others with higher prices).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a self outer join on the price being lesser. Supposing you have a table `products(id int, price int)`, you can find the `id` of the most expensive items using:

```
select p1.id
from products p1 left join products p2
on p1.price < p2.price
where p2.id is null;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=127ba69fa9ff035909b080e3a83163d8)